# Create a listener for all pages

Tags: jsf-2, listener

I have to use some **listener class to listen all pages**. According to the url, I must split it and get some informations.

For example :

```
x.domain.com/$member
```

I want to get the member name through url, get the following bean and retrieve some database informations.

So, I created a **PhaseListener** to do the job, but it is not called every times I needed it, for example in case of 404 error.

How can I proceed ?

Thanks a lot :)

PS : I am using Glassfish 4.1.

Comment: As far as I know, No listener, or any other JavaEE application component will ever be called in the event of a 404. The app server doesn't let an umatched request progress any further once a URL cannot be matched. You are left with standard web app error pages to handle your 404

Comment: Thanks for response !

So I have to called my listener for the custom 404 error page and render some compositions.

How could I implement that ? My listener being called on the page load ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which is mapped on both normal and error page requests:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>yourFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Inside the filter, you can then check by the presence of a request attribute keyed with [`RequestDispatcher#ERROR_REQUEST_URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#ERROR_REQUEST_URI) if it was being triggered on an error page or not.

```
String errorRequestURI = (String) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_REQUEST_URI);

if (errorRequestURI != null) {
    // Error page was triggered on the given URI.
}
```

Comment: Thank you BalusC, you're a legend ! I can now handle all pages from my app ! 

But tell me, how could I get bean from doFilter() method ?

I have to access methods in some controllers, and I was able to do it with PhaseListener. I look for answers on the web, but I do not understand everything.

Thanks again.

Comment: `@Inject` would be easiest if it's a `@Named` http://stackoverflow.com/q/2633112/

Comment: I have figure it out how to use the Inject method, thank you again. I assume that it is not safe to inject some EntityManager in order to get access to the database. I will have to get the FacesContext from cookie like you mentioned here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045242/how-do-i-retrieve-the-facescontext-within-a-filter

Comment: "Get FacesContext from cookie"? Not sure I understand .. Do you? As to injecting the entity manager, only do it in service classes (EJBs), not in managed beans.

Comment: I meant the second part of your answer from the link above. It is difficult to me to understand your responses due certainly to a lack of knowledge of the topic. I will look for on the net in order to find some inject with EM. Thank you for your time :)