# Set notification message as request attribute which should show after sendRedirect

Tags: jsp, servlets, redirect, message

I've created two sets of servlets: Views and Controllers/Handlers

- **Views**: Perform simple reads and forward data to *JSP*s
- **Controllers**: Perform database updates or inserts and send a notification to either a *JSP* or a View type servlet

Notification here is a status message for the user. Example: "You have successfully updated blah..."

If I use `requestDispatcher.forward()` in controllers and the user refreshes (after the Controller has passed control to view/jsp) the page by confirming resend there is a chance of duplicate actions being performed

If I use `response.sendRedirect()` I cannot seem to send any notifications  without setting these in the session

Is there a good design practice that helps here? Any good link to MVC for java w/o frameworks that handles this particular scenario would be appreciated.

I am not using Spring or Struts - just plain old HTTPServlets

Example - Controller:

```
public XServlet extends HttpServlet{
     public void processRequest(request, response) throws ...{ 
         //Do some stuff here
         if(success){
             setUserMessage("Hooray ur profile pic is uploaded!");
         } else {
             setUserMessage("Oh no! We couldn't upload that file its too biG!");
         }

         //Send the notification
         request.setAttribute("status", getUserMessage());
         request.getRequestDispatcher("editProfile.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Doing this means that if the user tries to refresh the page the control will again pass to this controller and some actions may be repeated unnecessarily.

However if I use `sendRedirect()` then I cannot show the status message without either resorting to a session attribute or appending it to the url.

Comment: *I cannot seem to send any notifications* What does that mean? What are you trying to achieve? Give a concrete example use-case.

Comment: Hi, I've elucidated the Q with a few more details. Notifications here mean status messages for the end user.

Comment: You answered your own question. Sending a redirect consists in telling the browser to send a new request. So everything stored in the first request's attributes is lost when handling the new request. So you indeed need session attributes or parameters in the URL.

Comment: I get that but now the status is stored in the session meaning once its displayed i have to clear it. Is there a cleaner mechanism to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: MVC frameworks have things called "flash attributes", which basically do what you're describing: when accessing them, they're removed from the session. Since you decided to not use any higher-level framework, you also decided to reinvent and redo by yourself all the features implemented by these frameworks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the "[flash scope](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flash-scope/info)".

> The flash scope is backed by a short living cookie which is associated with a data entry in the session scope. Before the redirect, a cookie will be set on the HTTP response with a value which is uniquely associated with the data entry in the session scope. After the redirect, the presence of the flash scope cookie will be checked and the data entry associated with the cookie will be removed from the session scope and be put in the request scope of the redirected request. Finally the cookie will be removed from the HTTP response. This way the redirected request has access to request scoped data which was been prepared in the initial request.

In plain Servlet terms that's thus like below:

1. Create the flash scope and add entries:

   ```
   String message = "Some message";

   // ...

   Map<String, Object> flashScope = new HashMap<>();
   flashScope.put("message", message);
   ```
2. Before redirect, store it in the session keyed by an unique ID and set it as cookie:

   ```
   String flashScopeId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
   request.getSession().setAttribute(flashScopeId, flashScope);
   Cookie cookie = new Cookie("flash", flashScopeId);
   cookie.setPath(request.getContextPath());
   response.addCookie(cookie);

   // ...

   response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/someservlet");
   ```
3. In next request, find the flash cookie, map it back into request scope and delete cookie:

   ```
   if (request.getCookies() != null) {
       for (Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
           if ("flash".equals(cookie.getName())) {
               Map<String, Object> flashScope = (Map<String, Object>) request.getSession().getAttribute(cookie.getValue());

               if (flashScope != null) {
                   request.getSession().removeAttribute(cookie.getValue());

                   for (Entry<String, Object> entry : flashScope.entrySet()) {
                       request.setAttribute(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                   }
               }

               cookie.setValue(null);
               cookie.setMaxAge(0);
               cookie.setPath(request.getContextPath());
               response.addCookie(cookie);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

This could be further abstracted using context-specific helper method like `setFlashAttribute()` and a servlet filter with a response wrapper.

Comment: BalusC thank you again....the amount of information you provide has helped me a lot.....

Comment: Is this generally what is used to display temporary messages of this kind and avoid having them be indexable? Are there any other options that you could point me to? Do some people do a `forward` instead of a `redirect` in order to solve this issue?

Comment: See the question. The asker themselves has already very clearly elaborated this.

Answer (score 1):

use bean to set request scope message

```
@SessionScoped
public class Message implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Message() {
}

@PostConstruct
private void prepareMessage() {
    messages = new HashMap<>(10);
}

private HashMap<String, String> messages;

public String add(String value) {
    if (messages.size() == 10) {
        messages.clear();
    }
    String key = generateRandomKey();
    messages.put(key, value);
    return key;
}

private String generateRandomKey() {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    return String.valueOf((random.nextInt(999999) + 1));
}

public String get(String key) {
    String msg= messages.get(key);
    messages.remove(key);
    return msg;
  }
    }
```

rediect

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse        response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
 //operation
String mKey = msg.add("some msg.");
            response.sendRedirect("mastercontroller?viewID=" + entity + "&mKey=" + mKey);}
```

and forward

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String viewId = request.getParameter("viewID");
    System.out.println(viewId);
    String mKey = request.getParameter("mKey");

    if (mKey == null || mKey.isEmpty()) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher(viewId + ".jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else{
        String responseMsg=msg.get(mKey);
        if(responseMsg==null){
            request.getRequestDispatcher(viewId + ".jsp").forward(request, response);
            return;
        } 
        request.setAttribute("postback", "true");
        request.setAttribute("responseMsg",responseMsg);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(viewId + ".jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```