# Missing FacesContext inside @WebServlet #doGet(...)

Tags: jsf, servlets, facescontext

I have some bean using the `@WebServlet` annotation:

```
@WebServlet("tools/httpProjectLoader.xhtml")
public class HttpProjectLoader extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to use that URL to react on links from emails, for example:

```
http://myhost/webapp/tools/httpProjectLoader.xhtml?pn=1000000654
```

The web.xml uses the following setup for the `FacesServlet`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I try to access `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` from within `#doGet(...)` the returned value is always `null`. **Why? And how can I handle this?** I want to use some UI (CDI) beans to init the application and forward to a resulting page. Whenever some code uses i.e. `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(...)` it fails with a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: This is a huge [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You basically need to ask this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10724428 Is this acceptable as dupe? The answer to the technical problem with the `FacesContext` is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14045242

Comment: @BalusC Thanks! These view parameters should help me out. I'll change my implementation to use a JSP instead.

Comment: ...to be more precise: xhtml page using JSF tags.

Comment: You cannot combine JSF with servlet, neither JSP, `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` are accessible in jsf beans. your servlet doesn't make any sense too.