# Spring session bean sees FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() as Null reference

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2.2

I have an `Actor` class that handle user session scoped data

```
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    @Component(value = "actor")
    @Scope(value = "session")
    public class Actor{
        public Actor() {
            System.out.println("Inside void init Actor..........");
            System.out.println(JsfUtils.getFacesContext());// This prints Null

      }
    }
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">      
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd">
    <context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="off" />
    <task:scheduler id="taskScheduler"/>
    <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="2" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="8" />
        <property name="queueCapacity" value="2000" />
    </bean>
    <task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" scheduler="taskScheduler"/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>    
    <bean id="contextApplicationContextProvider" class="net.main.spring.context.ApplicationContextProvider"></bean>

//    <context:component-scan base-package="net.main.x">//</context:component-scan> more goes here


    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="Default_Persistence_Unit"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
                <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jpaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="jpaTransactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

</beans>
```

In older project that worked fine so I supposed the version of JSF is the cause I'm using version 2.2.12 with Spring 4.1.4. I tried to downgrade JSF version or upgrade Spring version with no luck. Another problem is that `Actor` constructor is called multiple times.

So is there a hidden behavior here, is that true that Spring should see `FacesContext` since the request is mapped by JSF servlet or it can't since `FacesContext` is in another scope.

I supposed that Spring is initialized before JSF therefore it sees `FacesContext` as null if so how you order the initialization containers

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are those listeners mapped/registered twice? Do you really need to map `FacesServlet` to `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>`? And do initialization of bean in `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: @Tiny Sorry my mistake I will edit it

Comment: @Tiny And Yes I need all requests to be JSF scoped and using `PostConstruct` has same effect of the constructor

Comment: Does it make a difference, when you place those two listeners before `javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet` in `web.xml`?

Comment: I guess Spring is constructing your `Actor` bean, so it's not related with any JSF request at all. AFAIK, the faces context can't be accesed outside the JSF lifecycle, so this method should return a null value. However, you should be able to access JSF session and application managed beans retrieving them using the standard servlet API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have `LoggedInFilter` that is not posted on the question

```
public class LoggedInFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            Actor actor = SpringUtils.getBean(Actor.class);
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            String uri = req.getRequestURI();
            boolean isAdminPage = uri.contains("/cpanel/");
            if (!actor.isLoggedIn() && (uri.contains("/select-issue") || isAdminPage)) {
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.html").forward(request, response);
            } else if (isAdminPage) {
                if (actor.isAdmin()) {
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                } else {
                    res.sendRedirect("/404.html");
                }
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            SystemLogger.getLogger(getClass().getSimpleName()).error(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Digging the problem found the cause was on filters

**Filters can't see `FacesContext` cause `Faces servlet` is not yet initialized on the filter scope see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14046241/1460591) for more info**
so when injecting actor on filter it's constructor begins and BAM `NullPointerException` is thrown if you tried to use `FacesContext` at that point

My mistake I didn't really think the filters can affect the understanding of the question thus I can see that no one could solve the question at the first place sorry for all